# How to create support functions for gin index on custom operator class in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I created some custom operators for jsonb type and a class for them all. Problem is that when i create an index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name on table USING gin(column_name custom_operator_class)
```

I get an error

```
missing support function 2 for attribute 1 of index "idx_name"
```

I probably need to create support classes for overlap, contains, containedBy and equal, but i am not finding any documentation on how to do that. All i found online is for btree, and nothing for gin. Does anybody know how to do this, or any material where i can find some examples?

If you need more information, i will be glad to say more. Operators are basically for recursive search of keys where date is less than, more than, equal to the specified one

EDIT:

I tried creating support functions like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jb_custom_contains(jsonb, jsonb)
RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 <@ $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jb_custom_contaiedBy(jsonb, jsonb)
RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 @> $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jb_custom_equals(jsonb, jsonb)
RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 = $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

CREATE INDEX then doesn't return an error, but the operator won't work properly

Answer (score 2):

To explain your error message:

Support function 2 is defined in `src/include/access/gin.h`:

```c
/*
 * amproc indexes for inverted indexes.
 */
#define GIN_COMPARE_PROC               1
#define GIN_EXTRACTVALUE_PROC          2
#define GIN_EXTRACTQUERY_PROC          3
#define GIN_CONSISTENT_PROC            4
#define GIN_COMPARE_PARTIAL_PROC       5
#define GIN_TRICONSISTENT_PROC         6
#define GIN_OPTIONS_PROC       7
#define GINNProcs                      7
```

That is, support function 2 is the `extractValue` described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-extensibility.html):

> There are two methods that an operator class for GIN must provide:
>
> ```
> Datum *extractValue(Datum itemValue, int32 *nkeys, bool **nullFlags)
> ```
>
> Returns a palloc'd array of keys given an item to be indexed. The number of returned keys must be stored into `*nkeys`. If any of the keys can be null, also palloc an array of `*nkeys` `bool` fields, store its address at `*nullFlags`, and set these null flags as needed. `*nullFlags` can be left `NULL` (its initial value) if all keys are non-null. The return value can be `NULL` if the item contains no keys.

So the following is missing in your `CREATE OPERATOR CLASS` statement:

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS custom_operator_class FOR TYPE jsonb USING gin AS
   FUNCTION 2 myextractvaluefunc(jsonb, internal),
   ...;
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. I guess i have a problem understanding how that function should look like. I thought that i would be able to just use already implemented function because i'm writing it for type jsonb. And because i have more than, less than function, i don't understand how extract value fits in all that.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a strategy number with a support function number.

This is documented in [table 37.13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/xindex.html) and [chapter 66](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/gin.html) of the official documentation, and there are examples linked therein.

Comment: I made a mistake when creating the question. I meant support functions for overlap, contains, containedBy and equal. I read that chapters, and i'm still not sure. Because i'm creating an operator for jsonb, does that mean that i can use already implemented support functions for jsonb, or i have to create new ones?

Comment: I edited the question with what i tried to make it work with